# iptables: redirection local traffic from a local to the remote port

Tags: iptables

My question is: how can I use iptables to redirect all incoming and outgoing traffic from a given local port (127.0.0.1:port) to some port of another host?

I have an Android container (anbox) on linux host.

Anbox creates a network bridge (from 192.168.250.2 in the container to 192.168.250.1 on the host) which will forward traffic from the Android container to the network the machine Anbox is running on is connected to.

Anbox's ifconfig output:

```
x86_64:/ # ifconfig
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0 
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope: Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:30 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0 
          TX packets:30 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0 
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:1548 TX bytes:1548 

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 26:e8:ad:ef:c7:37
          inet addr:192.168.250.2  Bcast:192.168.250.255  Mask:255.255.255.0 
          inet6 addr: fe80::24e8:adff:feef:c737/64 Scope: Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:493 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0 
          TX packets:504 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0 
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:284033 TX bytes:141521
```

On the host, I have a web-server that listen 192.168.250.1:8085

How can I forward it to the 127.0.0.1:8085 of Anbox?

In other words, I want to open a browser inside the Anbox, type "http://127.0.0.1:8085" in the address bar and see the response from the host's web server.

I tried to do it in Anbox:

```
x86_64:/ # echo "1" >/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
x86_64:/ # sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.all.route_localnet=1
x86_64:/ # iptables -F && iptables -t nat -F && iptables -t mangle -F && iptables -X 
86_64:/ # iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp -d 127.0.0.1 --dport 8090 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.250.1
iptables -t nat -A INPUT -p tcp --sport 8090 -j SNAT --to-source 127.0.0.1
```

But I've reseived "Connection refused".

http://192.168.250.1:8085 inside Anbox works as expected.

So how can I do it?
Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I finally did it!
The bug was that I didn't replace the original address and the host's server tried to send response packets to 127.0.0.1

So, the correct solution is to write the following rules on the guest machine (Anbox container):

```
iptables -F && iptables -t nat -F && iptables -t mangle -F && iptables -X
echo "1" >/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.all.route_localnet=1
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp -d 127.0.0.1 --dport 8090 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.250.1
iptables -t nat -A INPUT -p tcp --sport 8090 -j SNAT --to-source 127.0.0.1
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp --dport 8090 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.250.2
```